# Windows Media Player 9 can't find auto playlist file

Tags: windows-xp, windows-media-player

I'm using Windows Media Player 9.

When I try to play any of the auto playlists, like "tracks yet to be rated", I receive the following error:

> Windows Media Player cannot find the
>   specified file.  Be sure the path is
>   typed correctly.  If it is, the file
>   does not exist at the specified
>   location, or the computer where the
>   file is stored is offline.

How do I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to open the playlist with an editor and have a view to it?

*.m3u playlists list the tracks sequential in a list, *.wpl playlists have a xml structure.
Both of them link to the single music files on your harddisc. For example:

## EXTM3U

## EXTINF:0,song 1.mp3

my music\song 1.mp3

## EXTINF:0,song 2.mp3

my Music\song 2.mp3

## EXTINF:0,song 3.mp3

my Music\song 3.mp3

## EXTINF:0,song 4.mp3

my Music\song 4.mp3

If you move your songs from "my Music\" to another location, for example "my Music\mixed\" the player is not able to find them. Often it helps to simply do a "find & replace" on the playlist with an edior: Find "my Music\" and replace with "my Music\mixed\" should do it.

hope that helps.

Comment: This is what you're looking for steve

Comment: There are no .m3u files, only 1 .wpl file:  C:\Documents and Settings\User\Application Data\Microsoft\Media Player\05BA5E32.wpl.  It doesn't contain much:
<?wpl version="1.0"?>
<smil>
    <head>
        <meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Windows Media Player -- 9.0.0.4510"/>
    </head>
</smil>

Comment: How can Windows Media Player generate new auto playlists?  Do I need to reinstall WMP9?  There is no repair function I am aware of, and it is not even listed in Add/Remove Programs.